# Error occured processing XML 'Unable to load class [org.springframework.transaction.annotation.AnnotationTransactionAttributeSource]

Tags: java, xml, spring, hibernate, applicationcontext

Please i need configuration of the file applicationcontext.xml, I use hibernate 5.2.10 and spring 3.1.1. 
I already have this configuration but there is an error :

> "Error occured processing XML 'Unable to load class [org.springframework.transaction.annotation.AnnotationTransactionAttributeSource].
>   Are you running on Java 1.5+?   Root cause:
>   java.lang.NoSuchMethodError:
>   org.springframework.util.ClassUtils.forName(Ljava/lang/String;)Ljava/lang/Class;'.
>   See Error Log for more details"

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns:aop="http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop"
    xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop/spring-aop-3.1.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.1.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx-3.1.xsd">

        <bean id="dataSource" class="org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource">
            <property name="driverClassName" value="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"></property>
            <property name="url" value="jdbc:mysql://localhost/training"></property>
            <property name="username" value="root"></property>
            <property name="password" value=""></property>
        </bean>

        <bean id="sessionFactory" class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.annotation.AnnotationSessionFactoryBean">
            <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource"></property>
            <property name="annotatedClasses">
                <list>
                    <value>co.ma.training.entity.Stagiaire</value>
                </list>
            </property>
            <property name="hibernateProperties">
                <props>
                    <prop key="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect</prop>
                </props>
            </property>
        </bean>

        <bean id="transactionManager" class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.HibernateTransactionManager">
            <property name="sessionFactory" ref="sessionFactory"></property>
        </bean>
        <tx:annotation-driven transaction-manager="transactionManager" />

        <context:annotation-config></context:annotation-config>
        <context:component-scan base-package="co.ma.training"></context:component-scan>

</beans>
```

Comment: You are mixing jars from different versions of Spring. Don't mix spring versions.

Answer (score 1):

Please make sure to use latest compatible Java version to the frameworks in your project. (1.5 +)

If you're using Maven try using the properties below.

```
<properties>
    <maven.compiler.source>1.8</maven.compiler.source>
    <maven.compiler.target>1.8</maven.compiler.target>
</properties>
```

Comment: I use Java version 8 (Jdk8).

Comment: I use a project web dynamic